# Issue with d3js and nested iterations

Tags: d3.js

I have to draw a graph by d3js. To represent a graph I use the adjacent list data structure.
Every item in the adjacent list is the destination vertex of the edge (the source vertex is the vertex itself).

According to this representation, my data is:

```
data = [
        { id: 1, pos: [10, 50], adj: [
                       {id: 2, pos: [30, 60]},
                       {id: 3, pos: [20, 30]}
                               ]
        },
        { id: 2, pos: [30, 60], adj: [{id: 1, pos: [10, 50]}]},
        { id: 3, pos: [20, 30], adj: [{id: 1, pos: [10, 50]}]}
       ]
```

How can I draw this graph?

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
    var vertex = svg.selectAll("g").data(graph.vertices, function (d) { 
        return d.id; });

    // NEW
    vertex.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return d.id });

    var edges = vertex.selectAll("line")
    .data(function(d) { return d.adj }, function(d,i) { 
        console.log(d); return d; });

    // UPDATE
    edges.classed("selected", function(d) { return d === selected; })
    .attr("x0", function(d) { 
        return d.pos[0]; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.pos[1]; })
    .attr("x1", function(d,i) { 
        return d.adj[i][0]; })
    .attr("y1", function(d,i) { return d.adj[i][1]; });

    // NEW
    edges.enter().append("line")
    .filter(function(d,i) { 
        return d.id < d.adj[i].id })
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("x0", function(d) { return d.pos[0]; })
    .attr("y0", function(d) { return d.pos[1]; })
    .attr("x1", function(d,i) { return d.adj[i].pos[0]; })
    .attr("y1", function(d,i) { return d.adj[i].pos[1]; });

    // OLD
    vertex.exit().remove();
```

P.S : I can't use the force layout.

Comment: You haven't specified what your adjacency list specifies, but you can do this somewhat clumsily with nested selections: http://jsfiddle.net/MR7sV/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I edited my question according to your comment

Comment: In that case it's even easier: http://jsfiddle.net/MR7sV/1/

Comment: Am I obligated to group the lines in a group?

Comment: It makes it easier with the data structure you have. But no, you're not in general.

Comment: Ok, will that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/). For the nodes, you don't even need that:

```
var vertex = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data, function (d) { return d.id; });

vertex.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.id })
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", "black")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.pos[0]; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.pos[1]; });
```

Then to add the links the nested selection:

```
svg.selectAll("g.lines").data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(function(d) { return d.adj; })
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(d, i, j) { return data[j].pos[0]; })
  .attr("y1", function(d, i, j) { return data[j].pos[1]; })
  .attr("x2", function(d, i, j) { return d.pos[0]; })
  .attr("y2", function(d, i, j) { return d.pos[1]; });
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MR7sV/1/).